# On a myisam table, Why is my Select extremely slow, but only rarely

Tags: mysql, sql

I have an index on Uid and 5 other columns.  99.9% of the time, this query runs in less then a thousandth of a second:

SELECT * FROM player_data WHERE  `uid` =100000089905929

but once in a great while, it takes 4 seconds or more.
The table is myisam and has 60,000 rows.  My mysql runtime info shows that the max # of concurrent connections was 21 (nowhere near my max for max connections or memory usage).

Is there any chance that the other indexes are slowing this down (maybe because the DB had to recalculate the indexes or something?)

The strange thing is how rarely it happens (about 5 times in 12 hours - during which 1000s of such calls would have been made).   What can I do to mitigate this?  (besides sharding)

Comment: Can you please post a `EXPLAIN SELECT...`?

Comment: are the other queries that run in parallel at the same time also slowing down?

Comment: I've had my linux box "lock up" for 5-10 seconds on occasion while it's flushing disk buffers or some other kernel-bound activity. Top shows nothing active, yet there's still a huge amount of disk accessing going on. You may be getting hit by this.

Comment: Here's the explain: 
id select_type table type possible_keys key key_len ref rows Extra
1 SIMPLE player_data ref mainIndex mainIndex 8 const 1

Answer (score 2):

In my opinion the most likely explanation is that the table is locked. Since MyISAM uses table-level locking, if you run an update on that table that takes 5 seconds to execute, and run your select statement concurrently, then the select will wait for the update to finish, and therefore take 5 seconds to execute.

Here's some good info on table locking:
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/table-locking.html

There are a few configuration options that may help depending on the cause of your contention:

- If the contention is between `SELECT` and `INSERT`, you can set [`concurrent_insert=2`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/concurrent-inserts.html) on the server to allow concurrent inserts even if the table is fragmented.
- If the contention is between `SELECT` and `UPDATE`, you can set [`low_priority_updates=TRUE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/server-options.html#option_mysqld_low-priority-updates) on the server to "Give table-modifying operations (INSERT, REPLACE, DELETE, UPDATE) lower priority than selects."
- If those don't help, you can try to speed up your UPDATE, DELETE, or REPLACE by adding indexes, or break your UPDATE, DELETE, or REPLACE into smaller pieces to make it run faster.

Comment: can i explicitly tell myisam to not lock the table?  either for the update or the select.  Note: I don't want to switch to innoDB because I already tried that and the performance is 2-3 times worse for my select queries.

Comment: There are a few configuration options that ***may*** help you.  I'll edit my answer to include them.